# Create list of check boxes inside list of groupboxes dynmically

Tags: wpf

I need To create a list of group boxes when inside each group there is a list of checkboxes , all loaded dynamically.
 i have created vm that inserts all checkboxes to all groupboxes:

```
ObservableCollection<GroupBox> Groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupBox>();
GroupBox group = new GroupBox();
ObservableCollection<CheckBox> content= new  ObservableCollection<CheckBox>();
group.content = content;
Content.Add(new checkBox());
Content.Add(new checkBox());
.
.
.
```

My xaml looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemSource = "{Binding Groups}">
    <ItemsControl ItemSource = "{Binding Content}">
    </ItemsControl
</ItemsControl>
```

If I bind only to the groups: I get nice groupboxes, but when I add the itemsControl inside, It does not work.

I get :"Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource"

where do I go wrong?
TX Tal

Comment: If each group has its own list of checkboxes then you need to create `GroupViewModel` for your group and inside it you would have a `List<Checkbox>`. Then you would have one `<ItemsControl>` in `GroupViewModel` and second `<ItemsControl>` and `List<GroupViewModel>` in your parent `ViewModel`

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1836f2e6-e175-4b2e-a738-20816d7fa11c/how-to-use-items-control-with-in-another-itemscontrol-itemtemplate-in-xaml?forum=wpf . I think you are mixing your model / view . Your model data should be a dictionary with string as key (group box name), and each item a structure that contains a bool. In your xaml, you should indicate that each outer item creates a group box and each inner item is represented as a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

*If I bind only to the groups: I get nice groupboxes, but when I add the itemsControl inside, It does not work.
I get :"Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource"*

this because inner ItemsControl considered as child of outer ItemsControl, so it throws exception when you try to set ItemsSource.

For multilevel, you need to set DataTemplate as o_weisman said or like below,

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Content}">
                    <!--control you need to display-->
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```